# Multiple ON conditions in JOIN using Fluent API

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-6.0

A little bit of preface:
I am working in EF Core 6 and was trying to create an SQL query using the Fluent API. The raw SQL query that I am trying to achieve is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [table] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [table0] AS [t0] ON [t].[field1] = [t0].[field1]
LEFT JOIN [table1] AS [t1] ON [t].[field2] = [t1].[field2] AND [t1].[field3] = [t0].[field3]
LEFT JOIN [table2] AS [t2] ON [t1].[field4] = [t2].[field4]
WHERE ([t0].[field5] = GUID)
```

I have the following in EF Core:

```cs
var query = db.Table
            .Include((e) => e.Table0Navigation)
            .Include((e) => e.Table1Navigation)
            .Include((e) => e.Table1Navigation.Table2Navigation)
            .Where((e) => e.Table0Navigation.GUID == request.GUID)
```

Here are the models for the schemas (extraneous fields removed)

**Table**:

```cs
    [Key]
    public int field0 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("field1")]
    public int field1 { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("field2")]
    public string field2 { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public Table1? Table1Navigation { get; set; }
    
    public Table0 Table0Navigation { get; set; } = null!;
```

**Table0**:

```cs
    [Key]
    public int field1 { get; set; }
    
    public int? field3 { get; set; }
    
    public GUID field5 { get; set; }
```

**Table1**:

```cs
    public int field3 { get; set; }

    public string field2 { get; set; } = null!;

    public int? field4 { get; set; }

    public Table2 Table2Navigation { get; set; } = null!;
```

**Table2**:

```cs
    public int field4 { get; set; }
```

The relationships/model in the context I have defined for **Table 1**'s entity is:

```cs
entity.HasKey((e) => new { e.field2 });

entity
    .HasMany((e) => e.TableNavigation) //Navigation from Table 1 to Table
    .WithOne((e) => e.Table1Navigation) //Navigation from Table to Table 1
    .HasForeignKey((e) => e.field2) //Represents Table
    .HasPrincipalKey((e) => e.field2) //Represents Table 1
    .IsRequired(false); //Needed for LEFT JOIN 

entity
    .HasMany((e) => e.Table0Navigation) //Represents navigation from Table 1 to Table 0
    .WithOne((e) => e.Table1Navigation) //Represents navigation from Table 0 to Table 1
    .HasForeignKey((e) => e.field1) //Represents Table 0
    .HasPrincipalKey((e) => e.field1) //Represents Table 1
    .IsRequired(false); //Needed for LEFT JOIN
```

The other tables do not have relationship definitions defined in the model.

- Important to note that it is possible for **Table** to have a `field2` with value but **Table 1** does not have a corresponding record that contain `field2`, but the result should still be returned, just the values normally gotten from the record in **Table 1** would be `NULL`
- `field3` is coming from **Table 0** (t0) on a join between **Table** (t) and **Table 1** (t1)

The problem that I am facing is that I can never manage to get it to do the join on both conditions, it can do it properly on the `field2` but I can never get it to do it on `field3`

Ive tried pretty much everything but still can't figure out, maybe on of you could help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: EF Core deals with entities and properties, not tables and fields. All ORMs try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. `Include` isn't used to perform JOINs, it's used to eagerly load related objects that aren't included in the `Select` expression. `do not have relationship definitions` they should be added then.

Comment: Please edit the question and give meaningful names to the entities and properties. Relations can only be defined in `OnModelConfiguring`. `Include` and `Select` use those relations to generate JOINs. It's unclear what `Table 1 does not have a corresponding record that contain field2` means right now. Are you trying to define a relation on a non-primary key field?

Comment: Then how would I go about doing the JOINs? And for the relationship definitions, how would I go about doing a [0,1] relationship?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
Regarding the `Table 1 does not have a corresponding record that contain field2` it is a bit complex since the specific value of the field that we want to do the JOIN on does NOT necessarily exist in Table 1.

So you could have a table t with a record like so:

(field0 | field1 | ... | field2)

   (a    |    b    |    |    c)

It is possible for Table t2 to NOT have a record that contains the same value for field2 as in table 1, i.e in this case, the table t2 does not have a record with field2 value c

(field3 | field2 | field4)

   (d    |    e    |    f)

Comment: You don't deal with tables but application objects. `public class Order { Customer? Customer {get;set;}}` already defined an optional relation between Order and Customer, based on EF's naming conventions. If you write `_context.Orders.Where(o=>o.Customer.Name ="x")` EF itself will generate something like `FROM Orders inner join Customers on Orders.CustomerID=Customer.ID Where Customer.Name=@name`. Instead of trying to explain what LEFT JOIN is, give meaningful names to the entities (not tables) and properties, so people can understand what kind of relation you're trying to define

Comment: WHERE ([t0].[field5] = GUID)  turns left join on t0 into a INNER JOIN, so, probably you need some work there too

Comment: @siggemannen
Yeah, that one is ok, it works fine as a INNER JOIN as well (in the raw SQL)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
I get that, but I need the JOIN to have the condition, because by the time we get to the WHERE clause its already too late to filter the data

Comment: The execution plan generated by the server won't be faster if you put the WHERE condition in JOIN. It's quite likely that the *same* execution plan will be generated in both cases. You keep talking about tables. You'll never overcome this confusion if you keep assuming that you're working with tables instead of *application* objects. You keep trying to write a SQL SELECT query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used EFCore 7, but this should work on 6 also.

I used an anonymous type to tell EFCore what columns I need.
It makes all the Joins as it feels necessary.

```cs
var id = Guid.NewGuid();

var data = ctx.Tables
    .Where((e) => e.Table0Navigation.field5 == id)
    .Select(e => new { 
        e.field0, 
        e.Table0Navigation.field1,
        e.Table1Navigation.field2,
        e.Table1Navigation.Table2Navigation.field4})
    .ToArray();
```

and I got a query

```sql
SELECT [t].[field0], [t0].[field1], [t1].[field2], [t2].[field4]
      FROM [Tables] AS [t]
      INNER JOIN [Table0] AS [t0] ON [t].[Table0Navigationfield1] = [t0].[field1]
      LEFT JOIN [Table1] AS [t1] ON [t].[Table1Navigationfield3] = [t1].[field3]
      LEFT JOIN [Table2] AS [t2] ON [t1].[Table2Navigationfield4] = [t2].[field4]
      WHERE [t0].[field5] = @__id_0
```

add more columns to the `Select` as you need them.